# Is mining still profitable in october 2017

Tags: mining-hardware

Hi guys this is isaaq from UAE.   I HAVE A QUESTION ABOUT MINING.     IS BITCOIN OR OTHER COIN STILL PROFITABLE TO MINE.     I WANT TO INVEST 100KUSD IN MINING.  I WANT TO PURCHASR ANTMINER S9.    PLZ CAN ANY ONE CALCULATE PROFIT JUST NEED RETURN CALCULATE.  AND BREAKEVEN DAYS.  OF MY 100KUSD.   WE MAKE OUR OWN ELECTRICITY.   MY ELECTRICITY COST IS ZERO.     SO IF I HAVE ZERO COST OF ELECTRICITY PLZ TELL ME HOW MUCH TIME IT WILL TAKE TO RETURN MY INVESTMENT AND ALSO TELL ME WHAT IS AVG DAILY INCOME 
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of good calculators out there on the web. Just search "bitcoin mining calculator" on Google and many will show up. Here is my favorite:

https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/btc

Answer (score 0):

Entirely depends.  Most efficient mining gear currently available is the Bitmain (who does offer volume discounts on larger orders btw) S9 running at 14.5 TH.  Electricity costs are by far going to be your most significant cost so depending on what your localities $/KW/Hour rates are.

Currently, where I live for example we pay about $0.096/KW/Hour so mining is still fairly profitable (assuming you can get the units in-hand in a timely fashion), and with Bitmain your basically always purchasing a pre-order.

You might want to consider also looking into diversifying your investment into more than just sha256 gear at this point so your not essentially putting all of your egg's in a single algorithmic basket ;)